# Snapping Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: android, view, horizontal-scrolling, snapping

In the Google Play store, there is a View showing screenshots for each app. It can be scrolled horizontally but it snaps to each screenshot. I need such a View in my app but I can't seem to find the API. Is this a standard View that I can implement, or is it a customized version of HorizontalScrollView?

[image: The kind of View I need (currently showing that Angry Birds has over 500 levels of fun)]

Comment: Use **`uiautomatorviewer`** and find out what it is. It sounds like a `ViewPager`.